# select mutiple columns from 1 table insert into multiple rows of another table

Tags: sql, oracle

how do I select multiple columns from table1 and insert into multiple rows of table2 if the values is not null

```
create table table2
(
label_id NUMBER(4),
level_name VARCHAR2(20)
);

create table table1 
(
level_name VARCHAR2(20), 
class_name1 VARCHAR2(20),
class_name2 VARCHAR2(20),
class_name3 VARCHARS2(20)
)


create table table2
(
   level_id NUMBER(4),
   class_name VARCHAR2(20)
)

data in table0
1, k1
2, k2

data in table1
k1, roomA5, roomA6, roomA7
k2, roomB1, roomB2

the result table2 
1, roomA5
1, roomA6
1, roomA7
2, roomB1
2, roomB2
```

I probably need to add another column in table2 to make it right.  perhaps table2 should be(level_id, room_id, class_name)

thank you so much for the any help

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
insert into Table2 t2
( 
  Level_Id,
  Class_Name  
)select 
   t0.Level_Id, 
   t1.Class_Name1
 from  Table0 t0
 inner join Table1 t1 on t1.level_name = t0.level_name
```

Do it with each class, just must replace Class_Name1 with Class_Name2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it, easy if you union all 3 select statements for each classname column.

```
insert into table2 
  select a.level_id, b.classname1
  from table0 a
  join table1 b on a.level_name = b.level_name
  where b.classname1 is not null
union all
  select a.level_id, b.classname2
  from table0 a
  join table1 b on a.level_name = b.level_name
  where b.classname2 is not null
union all
  select a.level_id, b.classname3
  from table0 a
  join table1 b on a.level_name = b.level_name
  where b.classname3 is not null
```

Comment: @bluefeet would do it with one select and a pivot, but I don't think it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the unpivot command?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Of course, this assumes you are using oracle 11g, which is an assumption at this point.

```
insert into table2  
select *
  from table1
unpivot
(
  level_name 
  for class_name in ("class_name1","class_name2","class_name3")
)
order by "Puchase Frequency", state_code
```

I don't have a DB to test with, but this might help. It seems like a clean way to do it.